# Pandas read_csv parsing '0' as FALSE in particular columns only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I parsed the csv through read_csv and then saved it to disk, snapshots are from the resulting file.
[Snapshot from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhVVs.jpg).
[Snapshot with FALSE filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jusPK.jpg).
Notice that there are 0s in other columns that aren't changed to FALSE. Only in this particular column.

```
target_metro = pd.read_csv('/home/output/data.csv', dtype='unicode')
```

I'm using this command to read the file.
I tried converting the format of column to 'Number' instead of 'General' which didn't help since csv have string values. I have pinpointed this error to parsing from read_csv.
I want to add that pandas shows a mixed dtype warning for two columns, those end up with FALSE values.
What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace like this:

`df["column_Name"] = df["column_Name"].astype(int)`

or

`df['column_Name'].replace({False: 0}, inplace=True)`

or

`df = df['column_Name']*1`

or

`df['column_Name'] = df['column_Name'].map({ 'False': 0})`

Comment: That would replace 0's with False values. I assume you mean it the other way.

Comment: This does not help. After replacing the values, I wrote another csv, it has the same FALSE values. Also tried replacing with None

Comment: I thought you want to replace 0's with False, Or you want to replace False with Zero?

Comment: Replace False with 0. The core issue is pandas reading 0s and 0.0 as False and as 'FALSE'. I replaced both with np.nan, that's the best code solution. Just deleting 0s from excel also does the job. What's intriguing is pandas showing only two columns having mixed dtypes, while excel only shows numbers. Pandas imports False instead of 0 somehow.